# Combine Array Value and '.png'?

Tags: objective-c, uiimage

I have an array value that I am returning in a `for` loop. The array value is the name of an image WITHOUT the .png at the end.

I am using the following line to set an ImageView to the image:

```
UIImage *foodImageSet = [UIImage imageNamed:@".png"];
```

Now I'm not sure how to combine the array value, `food.name`, with the .png when setting `imageNamed`

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the `.png` when using `imageNamed` so just do...

```
UIImage *foodImage = [UIImage imageNamed:food.name];
```

If you do want to concatenate strings like this then do...

```
NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", food.name];
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer:

```
NSString *imageName = [food.name stringByAppendingString:@".png"];
```

However, having .png at the end is not necessary and may confuse Xcode into using an incorrect image for a specific device scale.